# Merging Two Data Frames With Matching

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames df1:
[image]

and df2:[image]

I want to join these two data frames to get df3:[image]

Here is the logic that I am trying to build:

1. df1 is the primary table. The first row of DF3 is populated by searching DF2 for the same ID. The logic finds ID 1 at location A with a value of 50.
2. The second row of DF3 is populated by searching for ID 1 in DF2. 50 is already found , so the remaining 50 is allocated to location D.
   3.The third row of DF3 is populated because there is an exact match with location C of 200
3. THe fourth row of DF3 is populated with an amount of 250 in location A.
4. The fifth row of DF3 is populated with the remaining 50 in DF1 ( not 100)
5. IF there is no location match, DF3 location should be null / unknown.

Is there a join that i can perform to do this ?

Comment: Please do _not_ paste screenshots of code and data in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas - merge

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

or concat

pd.concat([df1]...[df2], axis=1)

For more information you can look at this link:

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.07-merge-and-join.html